# Arrow function and Inheritance in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to learn TypeScript using Barasat Ali Syed's Deep Dive.

I came across below code in Arrow Functions and inheritance. Please help me understand what is the significance of second **:string** in this line "**(b:string) : string**"

```
class Adder {
    constructor(public a: number) {}
    // This function is now safe to pass around
    add = (b: string): string => {
        return this.a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a return type of an anonymous function.

Comment: @zerkms : Is it because of TypeScript, that we have to specify return type and is it compulsory? I do not remember specifying return type in javascript.

Comment: JS is completely untyped. And in TS typing is optional.

Comment: @zerkms : Would it be completely normal if I use (b: string) instead of (b: string): string ?

Comment: TS would infer the type automatically from your code in such case then. In this case it would see that you `return number + string` that is of a type `string`.

Comment: @zerkms : Thanks for clarifying my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

```
(b: string): string => { ... }
```

Is an anonymous arrow function. The second `:string` is a definition of the return type of this function.

On your `Adder` class, you are defining a property `add` and assigning an anonymous function that expect a string argument `b` parameter and return a `string` value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.